# How can i pass two different query string params that represent one action method param?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, actionmethod

i've got an action method like the following

```
public JsonResult Index(string version)
{
   .. do stuff, return some data v1 or v2. Default = v2.
}
```

So, this action method returns some data, which can be formatted either as `Version 1` or `Version 2` (whatever output that is ... just know that they are schemantically different).

So, when a user wants to call access this resource, they the following :

```
http://www.blah.com/api/Index
```

nothing too hard.

they can also do this...

```
http://www.blah.com/api/Index?version=1.0
```

BUT, is it possible to make it so that the user can use the query string params `version` or `v`

```
eg. http://www.blah.com/api/Index?v=1.0
```

and this will populate the version parameter in the ActionMethod. Possible?

Comment: Yeah you can't use headers directly though browser if users want to navigate there manually i.e. type in the url in address bar, you CAN if you are doing all your requests though AJAX though - which I assume you are if your returning JSON? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ see beforeSend to add the header.

Comment: You can of course use the same idea, but base it off query string rather than header, depending what your requirements are for the API and its accessability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you could manipulate the action method parameter(s) using an action filter.

Basically just check for a 'v' in the `QueryString` collection, and if it exists, throw it into the `ActionParameters` collection.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var version = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["v"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(version))
        filterContext.ActionParameters["version"] = version;
}
```

HTHs,
Charles

EDIT: Making it a bit more generic...

```
public class QueryStringToActionParamAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _queryStringName;
    private string _actionParamName;

    public QueryStringToActionParamAttribute(string queryStringName, string actionParamName)
    {
        _queryStringName = queryStringName;
        _actionParamName = actionParamName;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var queryStringValue = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[_queryStringName];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryStringValue))
        {
            filterContext.ActionParameters[_actionParamName] = queryStringValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could call it like:

```
[QueryStringToActionParam("v", "version")];
```

Comment: Goo Idea. I wonder if it is possible to make it a bit more generic and pass in the *name* of the querystring value (ie. 'v') and then the *name* of the actionparamater (ie. version). So then we could use this action filter multiple times and on multiple action methods .. ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to handle the versioning of the API is to actually have different versions of the controller for each API version, that way you dont need to have all the checking for every version number in each action method. Each controller is only applicable to one version of the API.

Its cleaner (IMO) to me handle the versioning at the route time rather than action time. You can do this with a routing constraint to check for the version number.

In the below example, the controller V10 and V20 can only be routed to if the route contraint passed - i.e. the header was present, if no header the default (which is v2).:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "EmployeeListingv1",
            "employees",
            new { controller = "V10Employees", action = "Index" },  // Parameter defaults
            new { ApiV = new ApiVersionConstraint(ApiVersion.Version10) }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
                "EmployeeListingv2",
                "employees",
                new { controller = "V20Employees", action = "Index" },  // Parameter defaults
                new { ApiV = new ApiVersionConstraint(ApiVersion.Version20) }
        );
```

You could do it using the query string to pass the version like you are currently doing and just change to a route constraint, however I've found it easier to maintain using an optional header in the request. (its also more "RESTful' without getting into that whole debate).  No header means default (latest) version of the API.

Sample API Version constraint:

```
/// <summary>
/// Enable routing of requests to controllers based on the 
/// API version contained in the header.
/// </summary>
public class ApiVersionConstraint : IRouteConstraint   
{
    const string VersionHeader = "X-MY-API-NAME-HERE-VERSION";

    private ApiVersion _version = ApiVersion.Unsupported;

    public ApiVersionConstraint(ApiVersion version)
    {
        this._version = version;
    }

    #region IRouteConstraint Members

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string vers = string.Empty;

        if (httpContext.Request.Headers[VersionHeader] != null)
        {
            vers = httpContext.Request.Headers[VersionHeader];
        }
        else
        {
            vers = "2.0"; // set default here.
        }

        ApiVersion fromHeader = ApiVersion.Unsupported;

        switch (vers)
        {
            case "1.0":
                {
                    fromHeader = ApiVersion.Version10;
                    break;
                }
            case "2.0":
                {
                    fromHeader = ApiVersion.Version20;
                    break;
                }

            default:
                {
                    fromHeader = ApiVersion.Unsupported;
                    break;
                }
        }

        return fromHeader == _version;

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: that's a pretty kewl idea, actually :) i really like it. But with header values, i can't just call the api from a browser, though .. right?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something more to this old question... You can combine the techniques here and so support version selection by request header OR query string by changing the check in @Rosstified's answer to include a QueryString check:

```
        if (httpContext.Request.Headers[VersionHeader] != null) {
            vers = httpContext.Request.Headers[VersionHeader];
        } else {
            if (httpContext.Request.QueryString["v"] != null) {
                vers = httpContext.Request.QueryString["v"];
            } else {
                vers = "1.0"; // set default here.
            }
        }
```